# Redirect one interface

Tags: ubuntu, redirection

I have a server with two external IP addresses. One one eth0 and the other one on eth0:1.
Now I want to redirect one IP to an other server in the local network.
I've already tried:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0:1 -j DNAT --to-destination 12.34.56.78
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The psuedo interface 'eth0:1' is not a real interface.  It is just a label that is associated with the address because the older tools were kinda stupid and didn't permit more then one IP per interface.

To see this just look at the output of `ip addr`.  You will see both addresses  on the 'eth0' interface.

It would be easier to just re-write your rule to reference the IP address of that interface.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -source 192.0.2.1 -j DNAT --to-destination 12.34.56.78
```

Comment: And 192.0.2.1 stands for the eth0:1 IP adress? It is very important that the traffic on the eth0 interface (first IP) must not be redirected as well.

Comment: Yes use the IP that you want redirected.

Comment: @MarvinX There is no eth0:1, both IP addresses are actually on eth0. So you have to specify the IP address.